# Horizontal distance covered by an object from an initial height to the ground

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile

We are given: An angle $\theta$ with respect to the ground, its initial height $h_0$ and the final distance $d$. How can we find the initial velocity from this information?

I tried a bunch of things, none of which (I believe) were fruitful.

One attempt led me to $$\Delta x = \frac{v_x^2 \sin(2\theta) - v_x^2 + v_x\sqrt{v_x^2 + 2gh_0}}{g}$$, but I don't know how to solve for $v_x$ from this equation.

We have only learned Kinematics so far in this class, so I assume we have to use kinematics.

I don't want to give the constants in question because I want to work out the problem with the numbers after some guidance from here (I don't just want the answer). However, if they are necessary, then $\theta = 52^\circ$, $h_0 = 0.9m$, $d = 188m$.

Answer (score 2):

I just figured out the answer on my own so I'll post it here for the sake of the site.

$$\Delta x = v_0 t \cos \theta $$

$$\Delta y = v_0 t \sin \theta  - \frac{1}{2}g t^2$$

Where $\theta, \Delta x, \Delta y$ are all known.

Using the first equation, we get $v_0t = \frac{\Delta x}{\cos \theta}$

Now substituting into the second, we find $\Delta y = \Delta x \tan \theta - \frac{1}{2}g t^2$

Thus $$t = 2\frac{\Delta x \tan \theta - \Delta y}{g}$$

Then we can just plug it into $v_0 = \frac{\Delta x}{t \cos \theta}$ and find our answer.

In conclusion, $$v_0 = \frac{g \Delta x }{2 \Delta x \sin \theta - \Delta y \cos \theta}$$

Comment: I'm glad you put the extra effort into solving the problem.